# not able to run sails.js app using forever / pm2 in amazon ec2 / digitalocean ubuntu

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, sails.js, digital-ocean

I have installed sails.js (v0.9.16) globally  in amazon-ec2 / digitalocean ubuntu..

```
sudo npm -g install sails
```

created a test project..

```
sails new sailstest
```

then lifted the server.. it works fine..

```
cd sailstest
sails lift
```

i can see sails app homepage  on

```
http://<domain>:1337/
```

But when i am trying run it using pm2 from app directory,

```
pm2 start app.js
```

i am getting following error..

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sails'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/authenticator/sailstest/app.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/r$
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:151:5
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js:104:9)
at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:107:17)
at WriteStream.<anonymous> (fs.js:1668:10)
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:97:15)
```

I tried running using forever as well..

```
forever start app.js
```

getting below error..

```
module.js:333
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sails'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/authenticator/sailstest/app.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/node_modules/broadway/node_modu$
throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                     ^
Error: Cannot stop process that is not running.
at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/moni$
at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:11)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded to latest version of sails.js.. Now its working fine with forever and pm2...

```
npm -g update sails
```

Now sailsjs version 0.10.0-rc7 works fine with forever & pm2..